# Azure DevOps TaskBoard for Kanban (no sprint)

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

In my Azure DevOps project I have specified some sprints and I can easily see the Taskboard for the sprints I have defined.

Now I am no longer creating sprints for my project. I just want to use a Kanban board to monitor the task progress, but the Taskboard keeps "locked" to a specific sprint, for example the latest one.

The new work created in our project are now assigned to the "Release" interaction and no longer to sprints.

How can I make these new items visible on Taskboard?

Comment: Do you use Agile or Scrum process type? You can see it at project setting "Overview" page.

Comment: The project is set to Scrum

Comment: Sound like it depends on the Area Path of the work items created. On every team there is a default set of area paths that will show, as well as other area paths that will be included in the team backlog. There you can also select sub areas from a path. 

Go Project Settings (Bottom left) -> Team COnfiguration -> Areas and  make sure the areas the work items are created in is included.

Comment: I have checked I only have a single Area defined. It has Sub-areas defined. And the same name is used to define the area and the iteration of my new user stories. But the problem is that the Taskboard only allows me to set a specific sprint. But I am not creating sprints any longer....

Comment: Taskboard is for sprints. _"I am not creating sprints"_ - this means you don't _need_ sprints, which implies you don't _need_ taskboard, yet you _want_ to use Taskboard. Your want is self contradictory. If you want me to detail which board is what, and what can be done with/in which board, let me know, and I _might_ add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Product Board (Kanban) is tied to your area path and presents the **product backlog**. The Sprint Taskboard, as implied by its name, presents the **sprint backlog** and is tied to both your area path and selected iteration.

With teams following Kanban, I recommend using iterations / sprint as a "heartbeat" and enable them to use the Taskboard.

Alternatively the Kanban Board allows you to track both the Stories and their associated child work items (tasks, bugs, and tests).